# Google Workspace - how to add general emails

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

We have a Google Workspace account for our company using it mainly for Google Drive.
We want to switch our email system to Google aswell but I couldn‘t find a proper howto or explanation how to create info@ or support@ emails that are going to chosen members of our company.
How we can solve this? Groups? Aliases?

Would be good if all mails going to a certain mail, could be saved and stored aswell in an inbox.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for a `Google Workspace Group`. Each `Group` has an email address which can be turned into a *collaborative mailbox*. Members of the group have access to this mailbox which can be tailored in many ways.

Detailed steps for creation are available [here](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/167430?visit_id=637626429904338532-2162189933&rd=1).